# Safely allow certain HTML tags in WordPress custom Metabox field

Tags: php, html, wordpress, validation

I have created a custom Metabox in the `page` post type and user is allowed to write some description. (Or whatever he wants. It can contain links, decorated texts, even images).

But, when I echo them back to the front-end, it outputs just the whole texts without rendering HTML. That's because of `esc_attr()` filtering function I use when outputting post meta.

```
!empty($page_data['desc']) ? esc_attr($page_data['desc']) : 0
```

HTML renders properly when I removed it.

```
!empty($page_data['desc']) ? $page_data['desc'] : 0
```

So, is it critical to use `esc_attr()` ? How to allow certain HTML tags without making security holes.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to escape user input, if you want to have a secure website.

There are several options:

- write your own escaper, which allows some tags to be unescaped (bad approach, this is not guarantee safety because you are not an expert)
- write your own template engine to convert your markup to HTML (bad approach, you should use existing)
- use existing template engine or markup language, markdown can be great
- use template engine with WYSIWYG editor for better UX